# compare directories for files considering on file name and not size

Tags: ant

I want to compare the jars between two directories and copy those that are present in both to new directory say Dir A, and those that are different to dir B.

targets I used:

1)To copy jars present in both directories

```
<copy todir="B" overwrite="true">
<fileset dir="currently_built">
<present present="both" targetdir="X"/>
</fileset>
</copy>
```

2) To copy jars differing between two directories

```
<copy todir="A" verbose="true" overwrite="false">
<fileset dir="currently_built" includes="**/*">
<different targetdir="X" ignoreContents="true" ignoreFileTimes="true"/>
</fileset>
</copy>
```

These targets are not working, i presume its because of the size/contents of the files. Is there a way to compare the files only by name and not by size/contents.

Different task is neither helping.

Comment: See the set operations  [`intersect`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#intersect) and [`difference`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#difference). `intersect` matches files in both filesets and `difference` matches files *not* shared between the filesets.

Comment: @ChadNouis: it isn't working either, its considering size or contents i suppose. i want them to get compared only by name.